# A python user defined class exists as "phantom"?

Tags: python, types, paraview

I have an object, on which I check

```
>>> type(a)
<class 'paraview.servermanager.ViewLayout'>
```

but then

```
>>> type(a) is paraview.servermanager.ViewLayout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ViewLayout'
```

Moreover, `'ViewLayout'` is not in `dir(paraview.servermanager)` (which agrees with the error message).

**How is this possible?**

**How would I check the class of such an object?**

Since

```
>>> type(a) is paraview.servermanager.ViewLayout
```

throws an error, I guess

```
>>> a.__class__.__name__ is 'ViewLayout'
>>> str(a.__class__) == "<class 'paraview.servermanager.ViewLayout'>"
>>> str(type(a)) == "<class 'paraview.servermanager.ViewLayout'>"
```

are all equally valid alternative ways of checking, but not understanding the reasons behind what I observed is prone to errors.

Comment: you aleady did check the class, `type(a)`... that *returns* the class object. are you asking why you cannot find a `ViewLayout` attribute in the `paraview.servermanager` namespace?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Precisely. I would trust `ViewLayout` is the class, but the fact that it is not an attribute of `paraview.servermanager` puzzles me. I guess it could be a dynamic class, with which I am not familiar (even if the concept makes sense to me).